# Install Libreoffice 6.0 and new elementary OS icons

Tags: libreoffice

I'm using elementary OS Loki and I was wondering how can I install the new Libreoffice 6.0, possibly also setting up the new elementary OS icons (https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/6.0#GUI).

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help,

Luca

Comment: libreoffice ui on elementary jino looks like windows 95. How can i fix this problem? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here my fast reply:

**Step 1** Remove the installed version of Libreoffice

> sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-core && sudo apt-get
>   autoremove

**Step 2** Download Libreoffice 6.0 archive from the website in your Downloads folder:

https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/

**Step 3** Extract the archive, and enter:

> sudo apt install -f ./~/Downloads/LibreOffice*/DEBS/*.deb

As far as I can see, the elementary icons set is the default one!

Luca

Comment: It is not necessary (and in fact, not recommended) to remove the distro-packaged version of LibreOffice.

Answer (score 3):

Just install `libreoffice-style-elementary` from the distro repositories. You don’t need to uninstall your distro-packaged LibreOffice for the version downloadable from libreoffice.org. After you install this package, the icon theme will be selectable from Tools > Options > LibreOffice > View.